# Forever hanging destructor

Tags: c++

Commenting out some lines of never executed function definition fixes it though. How come?

Full minimal example I've ended up with while deleting unrelated code below.

```
int main() {
    auto tList = tokenize();
    tList.front()->~Token();  //hangs forever if the code 10 lines above is not commented, normally I'll have pop_front() here
    cout << "never gets printed";
    return 0;
}
```

Normally I'll have

```
tList.pop_front()
```

instead of

```
tList.front()->~Token();
```

it's here just to demonstrate it more explicitly

Promised code: (also on https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3b8fa11e90c617b35623ba5432050c3e#file-main-cpp-L68)
tokenizer.h

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SGREP_TOKENIZER_H
#define SGREP_TOKENIZER_H


class Token {
public:
    virtual ~Token() = default;

    virtual bool isChar() const {
        return false;
    }

};


using TTokenList = list<unique_ptr<Token>>;


TTokenList tokenize ();

#endif //SGREP_TOKENIZER_H
```

tokenizer.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

#include "tokenizer.h"

using namespace std;


class Char : public Token {
    char value;
public:
    Char (char value) : value(value){};

    bool isChar() const override {
        return true;
    }

};


TTokenList tokenize () {
    TTokenList tList;

    tList.push_back(make_unique<Char>('h'));

    return tList;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>

#include "tokenizer.h"

using namespace std;


class SyntaxError : public exception {};


class Regex {
public:
    virtual size_t match_part(const string& str, size_t begin, size_t maxLen, vector<size_t>& groups) = 0;  // groups is a vector of begin,end indices of matched groups (ParenRegexes) (to be able to recreate substrings)
    virtual ~Regex() = default;
};


class Char : public Regex  {
protected:
    vector<char> characterRanges;  // pairs -> lower and upper inclusive bound of matching a character (even lower, odd upper), size is always divisible by 2
public:
    Char(TTokenList& t, size_t& groupCount) {}

    size_t match_part(const string& str, size_t begin, size_t maxLen, vector<size_t>& groups) override {
        return 1;
    }
};


class SeqRegex: public Regex {
    unique_ptr<Regex> a;
public:
    SeqRegex(TTokenList& t, size_t& groupCount);

    size_t match_part(const string& str, size_t begin, size_t maxLen, vector<size_t>& groups) override {  // maxLen by nemelo byt 0:
        return 1;
    }
};


class OrRegex: public Regex {
    SeqRegex a;
public:
    OrRegex(TTokenList& t, size_t& groupCount) : a(t, groupCount) {}

    size_t match_part(const string& str, size_t begin, size_t maxLen, vector<size_t>& groups) override {
        return 1;
    }
};


SeqRegex::SeqRegex(TTokenList& t, size_t& groupCount) {
    if (t.front()->isChar()) {    // Commenting out this portion of code fixes the forever hanging ..
        a = make_unique<Char>(t, groupCount);
    } else {
        cerr << "syntax error, expected [^)]-*^|]" << endl;
        throw SyntaxError();
    }  // ...commenting out up to this point

}

int main() {
    auto tList = tokenize();
    tList.front()->~Token();  //hangs forever if the code 10 lines above is not commented, normally I'll have pop_front() here
    cout << "never gets printed";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Telltale sign of UB somewhere in your code. It would be nice if you could further reduce your example so that it fits in a SO question.

Comment: Whenever I merge it into one file the hanging disappears. I don't know if it can somehow be related to having two different classes with same name? But they're in different cpps.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classes called `Char`. They do not have the same definition. This is a violation of the one-definition-rule (ODR) and thus undefined behavior.

I'm just curious why you didn't immediately discover this when you merged the files together.

Comment: “Whenever I merge it into one file the hanging disappears. I don't know if it can somehow be related to having two different classes with same name? But they're in different cpps”

Comment: @Adam When you put two classes with the same name into the same file, you should get a compiler error. Maybe you forgot to merge one of the files? The ideone link posted by another commenter is missing one.

Answer (score 3):

There are, in totality, maybe a dozen unique scenarios where it is appropriate to directly call an object's destructor using the `~T()` syntax.

This is no such scenario.

If your intent is to delete the first token in the list, simply calling `tList.pop_front()` is sufficient.

Calling the destructor directly like you are is going to invoke undefined behavior when the `std::unique_ptr` object maintaining it later tries to delete it again. So you can't make guarantees about what will or won't happen when this code gets compiled/executed.

Comment: `tList.pop_front()` hangs the same way

Comment: also the cout does not get printed; it is before the potentially problematic (repeated) implicit destruction of the element (whole list)¨.

Comment: If I merge the code in one file, it does not reproduce the issue, too. Maybe that could be a hint

Comment: @Adam I tested in my local environment with the files split up as described by your Github, and wasn't able to reproduce it there either. Is all of your code present and up-to-date?